# Flutter error: There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an error regarding my use of the Hero widget. The widget was working fine before I made some changes to the MaterialPageRoute, but now it is not working. I have seen several questions posted on SO about the same issue but they all seem to be geared towards floating action buttons. I am not using a FAB so the solutions do not appear to apply to my problem. I believe the issue is being caused by the fact that I am using an index for the TripPackage grid view. It should be assigning an new index and tag to each image but it appears to not be doing that. I am getting the following message:

**Error Message:**

```
Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), 
each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: tag0

Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
  tag: tag0
  state: _HeroState#2a251
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0 Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:265:11)
#1 Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:276:8)
#2 Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:295:21)
#3 MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5534:16)
#4 Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
```

**TripPackages Hero**

```
Container(
   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       stream: Firestore.instance.collection('trip_package').snapshots(),
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.hasError)
           return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
         if (!snapshot.hasData)
           return Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
         final int docCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
         return Column(
           children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) {
             return GridView.builder(
               shrinkWrap: true,
               primary: false,
               scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
               itemCount: docCount,
               itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                 DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                 return GestureDetector(
                   onTap: () {
                     var docId = doc.documentID;
                     var indexID = document;
                             Navigator.push(context,
                                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IndividualTripPackage(docId, indexID)));},
                           child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                             child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                               children: <Widget>[
                                 Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                   children: <Widget>[
                                     Stack(
                                       alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                       children: <Widget>[
                                         Container(...),
                                           child: Stack(
                                             children: <Widget>[
                                               Hero(
                                                 tag: 'tag$index',
                                                 child: ClipRRect(
                                                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                                   child: Image.network(
                                                     document.data['image'], height: 160.0, width: 180.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                   ),
                                                 ),
                                               ),
```

**IndividualTripPackage Hero:**

```
class IndividualTripPackage extends StatefulWidget {
  final docId;
  final indexID;
  IndividualTripPackage(this.docId, this.indexID);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _IndividualTripPackageState(docId, indexID);
}

class _IndividualTripPackageState extends State<IndividualTripPackage> {
  final docId;
  final indexID;
  _IndividualTripPackageState(this.docId, this.indexID);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight),
                child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('trip_package').document(docId).snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError)
                        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      if (!snapshot.hasData)
                        return Container(
                          child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                      final int itemCount = snapshot.data['itineraryItems'].length;
                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Stack(children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 5.0, right: 10.0),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black26, offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0), blurRadius: 6.0)]),
                                child: Hero(
                                  tag: 'tag$indexID',
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                    child:
                                        Image.network(snapshot.data['image']),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
//Some more code.....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to provide separate key to each hero:

I think following code may solve your issue.

```
 Hero(
     tag: index.toString(),
     child: ClipRRect(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
     child: Image.network(
```

Here You are repeating it many time:

```
return Column(
           children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) {
             return GridView.builder(
```

i think just remove snapshot mapping and just return grid view will solve your problem like below.

```
return Column(
           children: GridView.builder(
```

Comment: I essentially got the same error which is "Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero-[<'1'>] tag: heroTag"

Comment: remove the tag and give it a try.

Comment: I think the tags are required. When I comment them out or give them a value of null I get an error message that says, "'package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart': Failed assertion: line 164 pos 15: 'tag != null': is not true."

Comment: tag: index.toString() can you try this?

Comment: It gives me, "...Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero tag: 0"

Comment: i think problem now lies in IndividualTripPackage page. add code of it. Because as can be seen in your error. it show multiple heroes share same tag and as i updated my answer now it should not. so add code IndividualTripPackage page.

Comment: I have updated my code example to include the additional class.

Comment: i think my current solution should work for you because it will not keep same tag for any hero widget. do you have only one grid view in one screen ? as can bee seen in your code right now.  where as in IndividualTripPackage widget you must have to provide same tag to hero widget to animate properly.

Comment: I think I found the source of the issue. I realized that the screen is repeating the gridview 5 times. I am not sure why it is doing this. There should be 5 items in the gridview. That part is being correctly presented but it is also repeating the gridview 5 times. I don't know why.

Comment: @Part_Time_Nerd i updated my answer check it. moreover, in IndividualTripPackage you are passing final docId; final indexID; is not require you can access using widget.docId in state.

Comment: Thanks Viren! That appears to have solved my issue!

Comment: Thank You!! it Solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, and was also not using a Floating Action Button.  What eventually solved my issue was that I changed my navigation from a Named Route to an Anonymous Route.

So I had this:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, DestinationScreen.routeName);
```

Changed to this:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
       return ProductDetailsScreen();  }));
```

Then the errors went away.  Hope that helps others as it took me few hours to figure out.